# how to displaysource file && line number information when using "bl" command in windbg to list breakpoints?

Tags: windbg

when I use `bl` command to list all the breakpoints in windbg, it outputs:

```
1020 e 004a62b0     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!`dynamic initializer for 'g_bInitialized''
1021 e 00491050     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!___mb_cur_max_l_func
1022 e 0049fb50     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!_ismbbprint
1023 e 004671c0     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!__sbh_alloc_new_group
1024 e 00469390     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!___setlc_active_func
1025 e 00463760     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!Is_bad_exception_allowed
1026 e 0049b4b0     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!isspace
1027 e 0044f790     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!__ArrayUnwind
1028 e 00490170     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!__init_monetary
1029 e 00488950     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!UnDecorator::doFunctionReturns
1030 e 004883d0     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!UnDecorator::getPointerTypeArray
1031 e 00456890     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!_set_winver
1032 e 0049c720     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!__tzset
1033 e 0049b9b0     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!_iscsymf_l
1034 e 0048b770     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!DNameStatusNode::length
1035 e 0045aeb0     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!_wcsicmp_l
1036 e 0048be80     0001 (0001)  0:**** wtltest!_mbstowcs_s_l
```

I wanna know the specific function in which file && at which line, then i look in windbg help file, it says:
If you enabled source line number loading, the bl command displays file and line number information instead of address offsets.

and i google it, use `.lines -e` to enable it.but still no source file && line number.
how to get those information?

Comment: I take it you have setup the source file location correctly? It's possible this may be a bug, which version of WinDbg are you using?

Comment: version:Windbg:6.2.8229.0.X86, the project is in debug mode not release mode, and the source path setting is correct

Comment: I just tested this and it does not work on my machine running same WinDbg version as yours, this could be a bug or error in the help. `.lines` is enabled by default in WinDbg but not for cdb so you do not need to enable it, interestingly this post shows it working for ASM bp:http://thefakejon.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/windbg-useful-commands-breakpoints.html, another way this could work but would be crappy but not using `bl` is to let it hit the breakpoint and it will open the source file (I find this annoying personally), you could post a comment on the blog and get a reply

Answer (score 0):

I believe "bl" only displays source/line number if the breakpoint was entered as a source breakpoint.  That's been my experience.